# Google AMP sticky ads with adsense?

Tags: adsense, sticky, amp-html

AMP is nice and fast but loads ads slowly. We use 320x100 adunit above the fold and by the time user scrolls down, it's not even loaded. Another is medium rectangle adunit in footer, which is almost ignored, we use wordpress and ads inside post content is not working so. So basically we're running with single ad.

I noticed there is amp-sticky component
https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-sticky-ad/
Can I use adsense adunit inside it or use google dfp and load adsense ad via dfp and show as amp-sticky ad.

Is it against adsense policies to use amp-sticky ad with adsense?

Update: Sent email to google, they said, they don't allow sticky-ads because they can't monitor quality of implementation.

Comment: sorry,can understand what actually you want to know?

Comment: Can I use amp-sticky-ad and show adsense ad in it? I tried loading adsense ad and it didn't work as well but loading from doubleclick did. So is it allowed to use adsense ad as sticky-ad only in amp pages.

Answer (score 0):

Google has given an offical answer for your question as below:

"AdSense does not allow the use of AMP sticky ads period. It doesn't matter what some other product is offering, AdSense itself does not allow it."

If you use it, this means that you break the rule.

You can view offical answer [here](https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/4487902?hl=en)